# Bayesian network and conditional probability

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

[image: Bayesian Network]

I am working on an exercise that find out certain probability based on a Bayesian Network. The Bayesian Networking showed on the above
The following are my work out:

P(C ∩ S ∩ E ∩ ¬P ∩ ¬F)
= P(¬F | C ∩ S ∩ E ∩ ¬P) ⋅ P(C ∩ S ∩ E ∩ ¬P)

= P(¬F | C ∩ S ∩ E ∩ ¬P) ⋅ P(¬P | C ∩ S ∩ E) ⋅ P(C ∩ S ∩ E)

= P(¬F | C ∩ S ∩ E ∩ ¬P) ⋅ P(¬P | C ∩ S ∩ E) ⋅ P(E | C ∩ S) ⋅ P(C ∩ S)

= P(¬F | C ∩ S ∩ E ∩ ¬P) ⋅ P(¬P | C ∩ S ∩ E) ⋅ P(E | C ∩ S) ⋅ P(S | C) ⋅
   P(C)

= P(¬F | ¬P) ⋅ P(¬P | C) ⋅ **P(E | S)** ⋅ P(S | C) ⋅ P(C) 
  (the deduction based on the above Bayesian Network)

Based on the Bayesian Network, E is depend on S and P, I am confusing on how to find out P(E | S). Does its probability can be treated as 0?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have modified my question. @José Carlos Santos

Answer (score 1):

> Based on the Bayesian Network, E is depend on S and P, I am confusing on how to find out P(E | S). Does its probability can be treated as 0?

**Exactly**, $E$ is conditioned on $S$ and $P$, so *don't do that*.   You use $\mathsf P(E\mid S,\neg P)$.

Just read the map.  $C$ has no parents. The parent of $S$ is $C$. The parent of $\neg P$ is $C$. The parents of $E$ are $S$ and $\neg P$. The parent of $F$ is $\neg P$.

Thus your network *tells* you that the factorisation is:

$$\def\P{\operatorname{\mathsf P}}\P(C\cap S\cap E\cap \neg P\cap \neg F)=\P(C)\P(S\mid C)\P(\neg P\mid C)\P(E\mid S,\neg P)\P(\neg F\mid\neg P)$$

---

$~$

Now if you *really* want to find $\P(E\mid S)$ then by the law of total probability and Bayes' Rule:$$\P(E\mid S)=\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{p\in\{\neg P,P\}}\sum\limits_{c\in\{\neg C, C\}}\P(E\mid S,p)\P(p\mid c)\P(S\mid c)\P(c)}{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{c\in\{\neg C,C\}}\mathsf P(S\mid c)\mathsf P(c)}$$